# Check for User Role in Autogenerated Endpoints of JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

let's say I have a JpaRepository managing an Entity and providing auto-generated CRUD-endpoints for creation and reading of said Entity:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "testentity", itemResourceRel = "testentity", collectionResourceRel = "testentity")
public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long> {

}
```

Since this provides pageable and sortable results I would really like to use the provided endpoints, but I want to restrict access to these depending on  User-Roles. Users are stored in the "session" field of the respective requests, sent by the client:

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("user")
```

Each user has a set of roles which specify their privileges. (just a List of Strings).
Is there an easy way to keep the auto-generated endpoints provided by JpaRepository and restrict access to them depending on the content of the user.roles field?

Note that Users are generated after previously authenticating via a third-party application. This means that the roles of each User are not persisted within a readable data-source, but have to be requested from said application each time a user logs in.

The login process therefor looks something like this:

- User sends username and password
- Application sends username and password to third party application
- Third party application sends back If User exists and their roles
- Application creates User Object with received roles
- User is used in session and discarded when session expires (This means that each user only ever exists for the duration of each session)

User Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> roles; 
    private String token;
    private DateTime expiration;

}
```

For Clarification: If there are 2 roles ("user","admin") I would want the POST Endpoints to only be accessible for Users with the "admin"-role Where as the GET methods should be accessible by any User (Both "admin" and "user").

Answer (score 1):

`Spring-Security` offers advanced options for restricting method access via annotations based on information from the security-context, e.g.:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin'))
```

These can be used on the repository interface (for all methods), or on a per-method basis.

Official example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/main/rest/security

(Depending on your security configuration, you might need to set the `Authentication` of the `SecurityContext` in a custom way.)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response! I guess I just don't know enough about how authentication is handled usually. Does the "@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin'))"- annotation Check for a field named "roles" in the "user"-attribute of the session and if it contains the String "admin" or do I have to set up configuration first so it knows where to look?  All the examples I could find (including your link) show an in memory setup which as far as I can tell is not really usable for me, as I need to frequently add and remove users and change roles and so on.

Comment: How do you create your "user object"? You need to implement your custom `AuthenticationProvider` whose `authenticate` method returns an `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` with the user data and the roles you get from the third party application. Then this approach should work.